# Data provided by OnAuthStateChanged shown in GetServerSideProps is not the same in client

Tags: reactjs, firebase, next.js, next-auth

I am implementing authentication by incorporating next-auth and firebase. I am planning to have two types of authentication: Google Authentication and Firebase Email Authentication. When I tried to implement firebase email authentication, I see inconsistent data in the server side and client side provided by onAuthStateChanged. In the client side, the value of user is null, which suggests that the user is not signed in. However, in the function getServerSideProps, this value is not null and I can access the email property. That means the server side reported that the user is signed in. Therefore, the state of user provided by onAuthStateChanged observer is inconsistent between server side and client side. I signed in the user by using authorize method in authOptions. I appreciate any guidances to fix this problem.

Here is the code for my main page (/main):

```
import HomeHeader from "@/components/HomeHeader";
import Feed from "@/components/Feed";
import ProfileSidebar from "@/components/ProfileSidebar";
import UserSuggestions from "@/components/UserSuggestions";
import { Flex, Spacer, Button } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import { motion } from "framer-motion";
import _get from "lodash/get";
import { createContext, useState } from "react";
import { signOut, getCsrfToken, getProviders } from "next-auth/react";
import { getServerSession } from "next-auth";
import { authOptions } from "./api/auth/[...nextauth]";
import { auth, firestore } from "@firebase/firebase";
import { doc, getDoc } from "firebase/firestore";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { signOut as signOutFirebase, onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth";

export const UserContext = createContext();

export default function Main({ session }) {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(_get(session, "user", {}));
  const router = useRouter();

  onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
    if (user) {
      console.log(user.email);
    } else {
      console.log("No user"); // client side prints no user
    }
  });

  const signOutCustom = () => {
    if (auth.currentUser) {
      signOutFirebase(auth)
        .then(() => {
          router.push("/");
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    } else {
      signOut();
    }
  };

  return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={{ user, setUser }}>
      <motion.div
        initial={{ opacity: 0 }}
        whileInView={{ opacity: 1 }}
        viewport={{ once: true }}
        transition={{ duration: 0.5 }}
        animate={{ opacity: 1 }}
      >
        <div className="h-screen w-screen">
          <HomeHeader />
          <div className="mx-auto max-h-screen xl:max-w-7xl mt-8 max-w-6xl overflow-y">
            <Flex gap={4}>
              <ProfileSidebar />
              <Spacer />
              <Feed />
              <Spacer />
              <UserSuggestions />
              <Button onClick={signOutCustom}>Sign Out</Button>
            </Flex>
          </div>
        </div>
      </motion.div>
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
}

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const session = await getServerSession(context.req, context.res, authOptions);
  const isSignedIn = auth.currentUser;
  onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
    if (user) {
      console.log(user.email); // this would print email
    } else {
      console.log("No user");
    }
  });
  if (!session && !isSignedIn) {
    return {
      redirect: {
        destination: "/",
        permanent: false,
      },
    };
  }
  if (!session && isSignedIn) {
    const userId = auth.currentUser.uid;
    const userDoc = await getDoc(doc(firestore, "users", userId));
    if (userDoc.exists()) {
      const user = userDoc.data();
      return {
        props: {
          session: {
            user: {
              ...user,
              uid: userId,
            },
          },
        },
      };
    } else {
      return {
        redirect: {
          destination: "/",
          permanent: false,
        },
      };
    }
  }
  return {
    props: {
      session: session,
    },
  };
}
```

Here is my [...nextauth].js:

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";
import { FirestoreAdapter } from "@next-auth/firebase-adapter";
import { cert } from "firebase-admin/app";
import admin from "firebase-admin";
import { signInWithCustomToken, signInWithEmailAndPassword, onAuthStateChanged} from "firebase/auth";
import { auth, firestore } from "@/firebase/firebase";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import { doc, getDoc } from "firebase/firestore";

export const authOptions = {
  adapter: FirestoreAdapter({
    credential: cert({
      projectId: process.env.FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
      clientEmail: process.env.FIREBASE_CLIENT_EMAIL,
      privateKey: process.env.FIREBASE_PRIVATE_KEY,
    })
  }),
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: "Credentials",
      credentials: {
        email: {
          label: 'Email',
          type: 'text',
        },
        password: {
          label: 'Password',
          type: 'password',
        },
      },
      async authorize(credentials, req) {
        try{
          const userCredential = await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, credentials.email, credentials.password);
          const userId = userCredential.user.uid;
          const userDoc = await getDoc(doc(firestore, "users", userId));
          if (userDoc.exists()){
            const user = userDoc.data();
            const userId = userDoc.id;
            user.uid = userId;
            return user;
          }
          else{
            throw new Error("User not found");
          }
        }
        catch (error) {
          throw new Error(error);
        }
      }
    }),
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    }),
  ],
  callbacks: {
    async signIn({ user, account, profile, email, credentials }) {
      if (user) return true;
      else return false;
    },
    async jwt({token, user, account, profile, isNewUser}) {
      return {
        user: {
          uid: user.uid,
          email: user.email,
          image: user.image,
          name: user.firstName + " " + user.lastName,
        }
      }
    },
    async session({ session, user, token }) {
      try {
        let isSignedIn = false;
        onAuthStateChanged(auth, (credentialUser) => {
          if (credentialUser) {
            isSignedIn = true;
          }
        });
        if (isSignedIn) return session;
        await admin.auth().getUserByEmail(user.email);
        const customToken = await admin.auth().createCustomToken(user.id);
        await signInWithCustomToken(auth, customToken).then((userCredential) => {
          const user_ = userCredential.user;
        }
        ).catch((error) => {
          throw new Error(error);
        })
        return session;
      }
      catch (error) {
        if (error.code === "auth/user-not-found") {
          await admin.auth().createUser({
            uid: user.id,
            email: user.email,
            emailVerified: false,
            image: user.image,
            providerData: [
              {
                providerId: "google.com",
                uid: user.id,
                email: user.email,
                displayName: user.name,
                photoURL: user.image,
              },
            ],
          });
          const customToken = await admin.auth().createCustomToken(user.id);
          await signInWithCustomToken(auth, customToken).then((userCredential) => {
            const user = userCredential.user;
          }).catch((error) => {
            throw new Error(error);
          })
          return session;
        }
      }
    },
  },
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
  debug: true,
}

export default NextAuth(authOptions);
```

Comment: I solved the problem above by having all authentication on the client side. After the user is authenticated, I save the user id into the local storage. That means a user session will always be there until I remove it manually (by signing out). Probably I have to implement a way to have session on the server side. Then I will retrieve it on the server side of the route that I am directing the page to after authentication

Comment: I realized that for each time the page (Main) is mounted, it requests a different instance of the application on both server and client side. Therefore, the user that I was authenticated would not be known by Firebase. A session package to keep data persistent between server and client side, such as next-session, may help